# Why can't I add draggable functionality to a regular <button> element with JQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The .draggable() interaction of jquery ui states that it "Enable(s) draggable functionality on any DOM element"; however, I cannot get it to work for the following:

```
<button id="btnWTF">WTF</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnWTF").draggable();    
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? Does it work on other elements? Are your imports correct?

Comment: You are going to have to prevent the default functionality of the button in order to make it draggable methinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..this cancels the default click event of the button.

```
$('#btnWTF').draggable({cancel:false});
```

Comment: This works the way i wanted. Appreciate the answers all! marking it correct when i'm able.